# Store procedure transaction rollback

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which is making call to 2 other stored procedure by passing the arguments. Example:

```
abc.xxssd.MES_LOG_PKG.insert_row(p_msg_guid,p_payload_type);
abc.xxssd.MES_PAY_PKG.insert_row(p_msg_guid,p_payload_type,p_payload);
```

both of these stored procedure do insert/update operation on 2 different tables which has parent child relation. I would like to put a rollback on procedures where if any error occurred on any procedure complete transaction should rollback and it should not enter any values into the DB.

In short, both stored procedure should not perform any operation.

Comment: here is my case... data is getting inserted successfully through first procedure but failing in second one..  so in my case I dont want to commit data in first one also..

Answer (score 0):

You can add into every procedure a try/catch clause:

```
begin try

 begin tran tr1

-- your instruction/query


commit tran  tr1
end try
begin catch

rollback tran tr1

end catch
```

For example:

```
begin try

begin tran 

exec procedure1(param1,param2)

--in ur case the first procedure works fine so we gonna save point 

save tran Savepoint1

exec procedure2(param1,param2)

commit tran 
end try 

begin catch

rollback tran Savepoint1

end catch
```

Note: this t-sql works only in SqlServer not in Oracle.
You can find equivalent [instructions for Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10001.htm#SQLRF01701)

Comment: Hi Simo - thanks for your response...


here is my case... data is getting inserted successfully through first procedure but failing in second one..  so in my case I dont want to commit data in first one also..

Comment: u can use a SAVE statment wish it save the statu of ur transaction it mean in case there is an errer the rollback cancel all the instruction after tha SAVE statment and before it it will be executed

Answer (score 0):

You want a block something like this:

```
BEGIN
    [... stuff here...]
    abc.xxssd.MES_LOG_PKG.insert_row(p_msg_guid,p_payload_type);
    abc.xxssd.MES_PAY_PKG.insert_row(p_msg_guid,p_payload_type,p_payload);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE;
END;
```

As soon as an exception is encountered, it will jump down to the exception block and roll back the transaction. Then it will re-raise the exception so you can see what it was.